# Quarkus Panache Mongo Transactions

Tags: java, mongodb, quarkus, quarkus-panache

I know that Transaction support for MongoDB is still in experimental territory... but I'm trying to use it in one of my projects that is still also in some early stages.

As I'm not using Hibernate... I've added also the JTA dependency just like so:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-mongodb-panache</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-narayana-jta</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

I'm using @Transactional annotation just like:

```
@POST
@Transactional
public Response addServicePlace(@RequestBody(description = "Adds a new record", required = true, content = @Content(mediaType = APPLICATION_JSON, schema = @Schema(implementation = ServicePlaces.class))) @Valid ServicePlaces services, @Context UriInfo uriInfo) {

    Service s = new Service();
    s.typeId = services.type;
    s.title = services.title;
    s.persist();

    services.descriptions.stream().forEach(c -> {
       ServiceDescription serviceDescription = new ServiceDescription();
       serviceDescription.lang = c.lang;
       serviceDescription.description = c.description;
       serviceDescription.serviceId = s.id;
       serviceDescription.persist();
    });

    throw new RuntimeException("BANG!"); ....
```

However the transaction is not rollbacked.

I have used also declarative transactional implementation - same behaviour.

For reference I'm using Panache's Active Record Pattern.

Did someone faced a similar scenario?

Comment: What kind of MongoDB deployment is it?

Comment: @prasad_ I have MongoDB v4.4.4 runnning on Kubernetes.

Comment: I mean is it a cluster (replica set or sharded cluster) or a standalone? Standalone deployments do not support MongoDB transactions.

Comment: @prasad_ ok... it's a standalone deployment... let me try your suggestion. Thank you

Comment: @prasad_ yep.. that was it. I was not aware that there was no support for standalone deployments. Nice one :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB with Panache didn't support transactions yet, see https://quarkus.io/guides/mongodb-panache#transactions.

Transaction support will be provided in Quarkus 2.0 (should be out in June), with it, you will be able to use `@Transactional` on a method to mark the boundaries of your transaction, no additional libraries will be needed.

Be careful that MongoDB transactions are available since MongoDB version 4.0 only and needs a replicaset to work.

Comment: Yep, I've seen your PR in GitHub - https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/pull/14002. Can't wait to use this in my project :)

Comment: @loicmathieu I am wondering, it looks like everything was released as part of Quarkus 2+, but I the Transactional annotation does not seem to work properly for my setup. I am running into the same issue as described in this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70615882/quarkus-mongodb-panache-transactional-rollback-has-no-effect. Any idea?

Comment: I added a comment there, I'll need a reproducer project to check what's going on.