# Quarkus MongoDB panache transactional Rollback has no effect

Tags: mongodb, quarkus-panache

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-mongodb-panache</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-narayana-jta</artifactId>
</dependency>

//repo 
@ApplicationScoped
public class ProjectRepository implements 
PanacheMongoRepositoryBase<Project, String> {
....
}

//transaction method
@Inject 
ProjectRepository projectRepository
....


@Transactional
public Project import(Order order, User user) {
    Project project = factor.from(order);
    projectRepository.persist(project);

    if (project.id != null){
      //try to throw exception manually
      throw new RuntimeException("testing");
    }
    return project;
}
```

I have tried @transactional annotation with mongodb 4.4.10 and quarkus 2.5.1. Transaction still has no rollback effect. any ideas ? thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I am running into the same issue. One of the requirements is to also run your Mongo database as a replica set.

Comment: I had a closer look at the logs produced on my end and found this: `2022-01-26 09:39:01,420 DEBUG [org.jbo.tm.TransactionManagerLocator] (executor-thread-0) Unable to lookup JNDI name java:/TransactionManager reason Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or in an application resource file: java.naming.factory.initial 2022-01-26 09:39:01,421 DEBUG [org.jbo.tm.TransactionManagerLocator] (executor-thread-0) Unable to instantiate legacy transaction manager: org.jboss.tm.TxManager`. Looks like this causes the problem. Wondering how to fix this?

Comment: So you're saying that the project entity was persisted to MongoDB even when the runtime exception was thrown ?
Can you please create a reproducer project so I can have a look ?

Comment: Thanks for coming back to me @loicmathieu. I figured what the issue was. The above logs had nothing to do with the problem I was facing. My transaction was not rolled back after a RuntimeException because I was executing both a PanacheMongoRepositoryBase.findById and a PanacheMongoRepositoryBase.persist within a single method annotated with Transactional. It seems that only the first call that gets executed is marked as a transaction. Hence the persist never gets rolled back.

Comment: I see that there are dedicated methods for multi-document operations which should be used instead, like persist(Entity firstEntity, Entity... entities).